# Is it ok to use unlink() to delete a folder?

Tags: php, unlink, delete-directory

Is there any downside to using `unlink()` to delete a folder (and its contents) in php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recursively delete a directory and its entire contents (files+sub dirs) in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-filessub-dirs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  `unlink` can only delete files, not directories.  You can delete directories with [`rmdir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php), but that will only delete empty directories.  You will have to unlink individual files first.

Comment: **Bonus:** if you look in the examples for `rmdir`, someone posted a function that'll recursively delete a directory tree.