# Apache (server's OS) owns folder that should be deleted. FTP client cannot do or change permissions

Tags: php, file-io, ftp, permissions

I did a quick install of a CMS (for a friend) on remote server. Then I rethought about it and when for another one (actually one recommended in stackoverflow). The CMS was MODX and I followed the advise to uninstall it: simply delete the subdirectory where it was installed.

Today, I have noticed that not everything has been uninstalled: there reamin about 30kb that have not been deleted. After inspection, it has been noticed that the owner/group is 48/48; and my guess (after some research) is that 48 is Apache who set non writable folder permission as they were created during the running of a (php) install script.

Therefore, as FTP user (I do not have root access in the shared server), I cannot delete this. But if that was created by Apache (hence the owner), would not it be possible that Apache itself (that is, a php script) changes the permissions to 0777 so that I can delete this unusable remains?

Any of you know of a PHP server file manager capable of changing permissions? something small as it will be temporary. Or if I write a short php script with chmod("somefolder", 0777); would I be able to delete the folder and the files inside through FTP?

I would appreciate your comments, I have tried writing a short php script but have not been able to inspect the outcome (except that it did not change the permissions on the folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take this script to remove the folder:

```
function rrmdir($dir) { 
   if (is_dir($dir)) { 
     $objects = scandir($dir); 
     foreach ($objects as $object) { 
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object); 
       } 
     } 
     reset($objects); 
     rmdir($dir); 
   } 
 }
 rrmdir("theFolder");
```

Source: [How do I recursively delete a directory and its entire contents (files + sub dirs) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-filessub-dirs)

Place the script in the same directory as the one to delete. Then call it with your webbrowser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply: this code has worked and has solved the problem. This also answers my question - since the install php scripts create the folders with special permissions, this php script is enacted by the same user, Apache, therefore it is able to delete (and/or, I suppose, to chmod if it was needed).