# how to set file permission to delete them in framework

Tags: php, yii

I am using `unlink()` function to delete the folders under assets folder that yii automatically generate. but it gives me the file permission error.
I am using wamp on windows. and also set the folder permission settings in the folder properties and also un-check the read-only option in the properties.
but still have the issue.
**error is `unlink(C:\wamp\www\mysite\assets\8ccb2dcf): Permission denied`**
my code is

```
$files = glob('C:\wamp\www\mysite\assets\*');
    foreach($files as $file){
    if(file_exists($file)){
        //here we need to give the permission.
        chmod($file,0755);

    unlink($file); // delete file
    echo 'inside';
    }
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to chmod before unlink? The assets files are owned by the web server user (the one that runs Apache).

Comment: I have set the rights for every users in the folder properties.

Comment: If so... try @chmod($file,0777);

Comment: Reading your error message, you first need to verify if you are deleting a file or directory, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir

Comment: I have also tried <?php if(is_dir($file)){
    rmdir($file);
?> but same issue.