# php-how to delete files from directory if files already exist?

Tags: php

I tried deleting file if its already existing .

But i ended up with no result.

Can any one help me with this!!!

```
$path_user = '/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.$send_id.'/';
if (!file_exists($path_user)) {
    if (mkdir( $path_user,0777,false )) {
        //
    }
} 

unlink($path_user);

if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$path_user.$path)){
    echo "Your File Successfully Uploaded" . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Organize your code, try this:

```
$path = 'filename.ext'; // added reference to filename
$path_user = '/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.$send_id.'/';

// Create the user folder if missing
if (!file_exists($path_user)) {
   mkdir( $path_user,0777,false );
}
// If the user file in existing directory already exist, delete it
else if (file_exists($path_user.$path)) {
   unlink($path_user.$path);
}

// Create the new file
if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$path_user.$path)) {                 
    echo"Your File Successfully Uploaded"."<br>";
}
```

Keep in mind that PHP will not recursively delete the directory contents, you should use a function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir)

Comment: i need to delete only the file inside directory.if i use this will it delete the file?? because unlink  function returns TRUE on success, or FALSE on failure.

Comment: This will create the dir if it doesn't exist. 
Then it will check if the file exists, and if it exists will delete it.
Then it will move the new file to the location.

If the directory has the right permissions the unlink will always return true, because there will be no access problems.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you missing else condition ?? And file_name variable :

```
$file_name = 'sample.jpg';

$path_user = '/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.$send_id.'/';

if (!file_exists($path_user.$file_name)) 
{                   
  if (mkdir( $path_user,0777,false )) {

  }

} else {

  unlink($path_user.$file_name);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i am doing is if user click on edit button and upload the same file which is already exist .its not getting updated ....because  both the files having same name..but file is getting uploaded successfully(if it is updated i trigger email)

Comment: No.It says file uploaded successfully but there was an error while updating.

Comment: not sure what you mean??? Why 2 status successfully and error together? Was it echoed out "Your File Successfully Uploaded" string??

Comment: Exactly what i am doing is if a user edits any of the filed in the form on save(Button) it gets updated and triggers mail.if filed is not changed it shows an error .Yes if file uploads i have echoed.Here what its doing is same file name right so it thinks no file change so no update..and normally its giving file upload.

Comment: if any suggestion please let me know.