# RecursiveIteratorIterator acts weird when using along with unlink function

Tags: php, iteration

I have a folder with 706 files in it. Which simply stores cropped thumbnails. From time to time I need it to be wiped clean. So I created function that utilizes the RecursiveDirectoryIterator to wipe those files. Here is my function:

```
function wipeDir($path)
{
    $i = 0;
    $src = realpath(get_home_path().$path);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($src, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($files as $filename => $fileInfo) {
        $i++;
        unlink($filename);
    }

    return $i; 
}
```

The problem is that if I use unlink function it processes only 527 files and $i= 527 when I run this function twice it wipes all the files within this directory, but if I comment the unlink function $i=706 which is a correct number of items within this folder. 
Somehow unlink function breaks from the iterator when it reaches files 527. Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange php behavior Recursive folder deletion removes only 527 file rather than all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478760/strange-php-behavior-recursive-folder-deletion-removes-only-527-file-rather-than)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with my vagrant homestead box... It works fine on my production service and deletes all the files but same does not apply to local development environment.