# Is it possible to delete folder and it contained file in localhost?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've been trying to delete folder and the files in it. The code return no error but the folder is not removed. I am sure the path is correct. What do i miss ?

```
  function delete_avatar($id) {
             $dir = base_url()."assets/uploads/Avatar/".$id; 

            foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
            if(is_dir($file)) rrmdir($file); else unlink($file); 
            } rmdir($dir); 
    }
```

Comment: Did you define `rrmdir` function? PHP doesn't have it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recursively delete a directory and its entire contents (files + sub dirs) in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir)

Comment: Use FCPATH instead of base_url() for removal of files or directories.

Answer (score 0):

**rmdir not rrmidr**

```
        foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
        if(is_dir($file)) rmdir($file); else unlink($file); 
        } rmdir($dir); 
}
```