# Recursive delete function doesn't delete folders with curly brackets in the name

Tags: php, file, glob, rmdir

I'm using the following function to delete all files and subfolders from a folder, before removing the folder itself:

```
public function deleteDownload($dir): void
{
    foreach(glob($dir . '/{,.}[!.,!..]*',GLOB_MARK|GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {

        if(is_dir($file)) {
            $this->deleteDownload($file);
        }
        else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

This works great, until the program stumbles upon a directory with braces in the name, e.g: `{test}`. When this happens, the program throws an exception saying that the directory is not empty, which is correct as it contains files that should have been deleted:

`ErrorException rmdir(/Users/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/storage/app/c544946e914f/test//{test}/): Directory not empty`

When I rename the filename from `{test}` to `test` everything works as expected.

Can someone explain to me why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: Alternative approaches can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, thank you, the accepted solution works. But I'm curious why that works while this doesn't.

Comment: That is the reason why I put that as a comment rather than close it as a duplicate.  It is useful to sometimes to understand what is going on in any solution.