# Unlink uploading folder in filePath Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-8, rest

```
$data = Student::find($id);
$filePath = $data['photo'];
unlink($filePath);
```

`$filepath` hold a value like this - `storage/other-document/images-1/jj.png` ,because am storing the file `jj.png` inside the folder `images-1`. `images-1` is a custom created folder. The unlink function here deletes the file from this `images-1`folder . but i want the `images-1` folder also to get deleted along with this. Is it possible? How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at some recursive way to do it : [How do I recursively delete a directory and its entire contents (files + sub dirs) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir)

Or in your case, simply get the path of the folder after unlink the file :

```
$filePath = $data['photo'];
unlink($filePath);
$folder = dirname($filePath);
rmdir($folder);
```